# Simulate button click in a Metro Style App

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, visual-studio-2012, winrt-xaml

I am in the process of building a metro style app and I need to know if there is a way to fire button clicks programmatically.

I have this PasswordBox and button in my xaml:

```
<PasswordBox IsPasswordRevealButtonEnabled="True" KeyDown="On_text_KeyDown" x:Name="SomePW" FontSize="50" KeyDown="On_text_KeyDown" Margin="0,0,0,190" Height="67" Width="363"/>
<Button Background="White" x:Name="Button_Go" Foreground="Black" Margin="20,0,0,190" Content="Go" FontSize="20" Click="Go_click" Height="67" Width="60"/>
```

And in my C# code this is the function that handles the key press in the PasswordBox:

```
private void On_text_KeyDown(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        KeyEventArgs K = (KeyEventArgs)e;

        if (K.Key == Windows.System.VirtualKey.Enter)
        {
            //<TO-DO> Simulate Button Click Here
        }

    }
```

The problem is I can't seem to find a way to simulate the button click... Can someone help please?

Comment: are you asking about _visually_ simulating the button click?

Comment: @ColeJohnson This is but a sample/test app... your comment is off-topic and is kind of offensive..

Comment: @Tim no I just want to post a click event

Comment: @RedSerpant ok. Not being offensive. It just kills me when I see that stuff though. Sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is there a problem with simply calling this or are you looking for a generic way to invoke a Click event on any button, perhaps to automate it?

```
Go_click(this, new RoutedEventArgs());
```

Comment: There isnt but i was looking for a way to signal the click event

Comment: Seems like it might be possible by writing a desktop app that will control your Metro Style App, but not from inside of a Metro Style App. See http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/498588ae-51c0-43c9-8f31-e3d960f00297

Comment: I haven't found any other way to do so but directly calling the click method. So I'll accept this as an answer.. And am not gonna go all the way on creating a new app just so it simulates a click when a user hits enter on an edit box... thx.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
ButtonAutomationPeer peer = new ButtonAutomationPeer( someButton );
IInvokeProvider invokeProv =  peer.GetPattern( PatternInterface.Invoke ) as InvokeProvider;
invokeProv.Invoke();
```

Another option is the following:

```
SomeButton.RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(Button.ClickEvent));
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: These APIs are not supported in WinRT which I am guessing is what this question is about?

Comment: @FilipSkakun yes i am actually looking for an alternative to this